# Services sometimes don't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service

This is my code
MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service {
   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        //My database upload code
        }

    }

    private void ping() {
        try {

            BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
            backgroundTask.execute(); //Running asynctask
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        scheduleNext();
    }

    private void scheduleNext() {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ping();
            }
        }, 300000);
    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int x, int y) {
        mHandler = new android.os.Handler();
        ping();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

autostart.java

```
public class autostart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        intent=new Intent(context,MyService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

In AndroidManifest.xml i have these:

```
android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
<receiver android:name=".autostart">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
<service android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            >
        </service>
```

I sometimes see this in logcat

```
02-04 19:57:25.125 10329-10377/com.example.pc.googlemaps I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
02-04 19:57:25.135 10329-10377/com.example.pc.googlemaps E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
02-04 19:57:25.135 10329-10377/com.example.pc.googlemaps E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
```

This service sometimes doesn't run sometimes run correctly. I check Application Manager from my phone and i see that it runs but as i said sometimes my codes work sometimes doesn't work. For example when i switch on my phone new, i check App Manager and service of my program runs. I couldn't solve where is problem.
I mean, it seems MyService always runs in App Manager but codes sometimes run sometimes doesn't run.
And i noticed that, when i check App Manager from my phone, if MyService is 4-5 MB, it doesnt run, if 13-15 MB it runs. I dont know it is coincidence or not.
Thanks for your help

Comment: what this has to do with Android Studio ?

Comment: I have a database that saves langitude and longitutude of user. This service uploads them per 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

please check this out
this is my service that getting coordinate every 15 sec and save it to SQLITE, send all the saved coordinates to server every 5 minutes and send an complete coordinates + address to server every 10 minutes
don't mind the content of `onDestroy` method
it's just my private library

FYI: dont use handler in `onCreate` method, it'll cause your apps become not responding
believe me, I've try it before
instead use `AlarmManager` for a better performance

```
public class service extends Service{

private AlarmManager alarm;
private PendingIntent addData, sendData, fullData;

// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(!App.User.GetUserCode().equals("")){
        App.DataFrame.InfoLog("Location is turned OFF");
        App.DataFrame.Off();

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                stopAlarm();

                Intent stoploc = new Intent(service.this, LocationProvider.class);
                service.this.stopService(stoploc);

                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();

                App.User.Logout();
                App.Toast("Stopping Service");

            }
        }, 1000);

    }else{
        stopAlarm();

        Intent stoploc = new Intent(service.this, LocationProvider.class);
        service.this.stopService(stoploc);

        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();

        App.Toast("Stopping Service");
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void stopAlarm(){
    alarm.cancel(addData);
    alarm.cancel(sendData);
    alarm.cancel(fullData);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    App.Toast("Starting Services");

    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(App.GetContext().ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CoorReceiver.class);
    addData = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent.putExtra("Code", 0), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    sendData =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent.putExtra("Code", 1), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    fullData =  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2, intent.putExtra("Code", 2), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 15000, 15000, addData);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 30000, 30000, sendData);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 600000, 600000, fullData);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent2, 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setContentTitle("Imagine")
            .setContentText("Service is Running")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1234, noti);
    return START_STICKY;
}
}
```